# How do I identify whether an object is an Eigen type?

Tags: c++, eigen

Suppose I want to know whether a type is an `Eigen` object, as opposed to a primitive or some other class. How do I achieve this without actually casting the object?

```
template <typename Derived>
EigenBase<Derived> fun(const EigenBase<Derived>& value)
{
  // This is bad, because value is now of type EigenBase<Derived> and I don't know
  // what the original type is.
  return value;
}

template <typename T>
T fun(const T& value)
{
  // This will also catch primitives and other classes.
  return value;
}
```

How can I catch *only* types which can be type-deduced to `Eigen::EigenBase<T>`, without actually casting them to that type?

Comment: You could use [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

Comment: @juanchopanza Cool I didn't know about that, but what type do I use? I don't know what `Derived` is in this instance...

Comment: Actually, "How can I catch only types which can be type-deduced to Eigen::EigenBase<T>, without actually casting them to that type?" That is what you do in your first example. I think you need to re-formulate your problem, because right now it looks like what you need is to figure out how to return a value of a derived class given a reference to its base.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't know what you mean; in the first example `value` is of type `EigenBase<Derived` and I have no idea what the original value was. I am trying to achieve what the 2nd example is doing, but _only_ for types which _could_ be received by the 1st example.

Comment: Your question is focused on "How do I identify whether an object is an Eigen type?". Let me quote some more: "Suppose I want to know whether a type is an Eigen object, as opposed to a primitive or some other class..." That is easy. The problem you are trying to solve is a different one.

Comment: @juanchopanza "*That is easy*" - Great! How do I do it, _without_ casting and losing the original type?

Comment: You just did it, in the first version of the function. There is no casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version, the actuel expression type is `Derived`, and you can get it via the `.derived()` member:

```
template <typename Derived>
typename Derived::PlainObject fun(const EigenBase<Derived>& a_value)
{
  const Derived &value(a_value.derived());     // the actual expression object
  typename Derived::PlainObject ret;           // this is an object with storage, typically the Matrix<> type closest to Derived.
  ret = 2*value;
  return ret;
}
```

Moreover you should never returns by value, and more generally create, an EigenBase<> object. EigenBase has no storage at all, it is like an abstract base class.

Comment: Thanks ggael; will this function force evaluation of `2*value` on return? If so, how can I return by value the expression only?

Comment: then you have to write down the complete type of the expression which can become very complicated, or use C++11 auto. But be careful, it is not possible to return expressions involving temporaries.

Answer (score 2):

You may use SFINAE and `std::is_base_of`:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<EigenBase<T>, T>::value, T>::type
fun(const T& value)
{
  // This will be enabled only for class which derive from EigenBase<T>.
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typebame T>
class IsEigen
{
public:
    enum 
    {
        value = 0;
    }
};

template<>
class IsEigen<Eigen>
{
public:
    enum
    {
        value = 1;
    }
};

template<typename Derived>
EigenBase<Derived> fun(const EigenBase<Derived>& value)
{
    if(IsEigen<Derived>::value)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```